invoke_result_t unable to deduce overloaded functions
I have a template function to invoke methods on an objects or static members of a class.
class Helper
{
public:
    static std::string getSomething()
    {
        return "None";
    }

    static std::string getSomething(const std::string& ref)
    {
        return ref;
    }
};



template <typename Func, typename... Args>
inline std::invoke_result_t<Func, Args...> dosomething(Func&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0) 
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(f));
    else 
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Invoke " << dosomething(&Helper::getSomething, "test");
    std::cout << "Invoke " << dosomething(&Helper::getSomething);
}

I want to write a generic "dosomething" where I can wrap exception handling and other common code around the actual action to be done. This gives compilation error
>------ Build started: Project: Template_TEst, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Template_TEst.cpp
Template_TEst.cpp(41,31): error C2672: 'dosomething': no matching overloaded function found
Template_TEst.cpp(41,31): error C2783: '_Select_invoke_traits<_Callable,_Args...>::type dosomething(Func &&,Args &&...)': could not deduce template argument for 'Func'
Template_TEst.cpp(26): message : see declaration of 'dosomething'
Template_TEst.cpp(42,31): error C2672: 'dosomething': no matching overloaded function found
Template_TEst.cpp(42,31): error C2783: '_Select_invoke_traits<_Callable,_Args...>::type dosomething(Func &&,Args &&...)': could not deduce template argument for 'Func'
Template_TEst.cpp(26): message : see declaration of 'dosomething'
Done building project "Template_TEst.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

If I rename one of the overloads of getSomething to something else the code works fine. Is this an issue with overload resolution or an syntactical issue with  defining the template.
I tried compiling this code with C++17 in Visual Studio 2019. I was expecting to setup a mechanism for any  method to be invoked via dosomething wrapper.

You can't take the address of an overload set

@patrickRobers could you elaborate on this please?

If you have void f(){} void f(int) {}, you can't just write &f because the compiler has no way of knowing which f you mean. (Except in certain contexts where the overload resolution can in fact be performed, e.g. void (*pf)(int) = &f;). There is no such thing as "a pointer to a family of overloaded functions, to be resolved later when a call is made through that pointer".

You can write e.g. dosomething(static_cast<std::string(*)(const std::string&)>(&Helper::getSomething), "test"), but I suspect that's not quite the syntax you had in mind. A cast is one of those contexts where taking an address of a set of overloaded functions is allowed (of course, the overload resolution is performed to pick a function that matches the target type of the cast). dosomething<std::string(*)(const std::string&)>(&Helper::getSomething, "test") would also work.

@igorTandetnik, thank you for your explanation.
